# Cant identify slice id/ series id using VTK (vtkDICOMImageReader)

Tags: python, c++, vtk, dicom, point-cloud-library

I have two flavors of DICOM data, the first works with my existing code (what I built it on), but I can not import the second.

First style has a bottom level folder with all the slices from one scan in that folder (in ordered ".dcm" files).  I simply point vtk to the directory using this code:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMImageReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMImageReader>::New();
reader->SetDirectoryName(dicomDirectory.c_str());
reader->Update();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> sliceData = reader->GetOutput();
double tempIntensity = sliceData->GetScalarComponentAsDouble(x, y, z, 0);
```

This is not the direct source (I check dimensions and set up iterating through and such).  But in short, it works... I have pulled in several different dicom volumes through this method. (and have inspected and manipulated the resulting volume clouds)

---

This depends on VTK interpreting the directory though.  It is stated here: that there are some particulars about [what VTK is capable of managing](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDICOMImageReader.html#a49fe4c37e794e6a6aac5943b5d3cebe2) (under detailed description, warning) in terms of DICOM data. (I am not sure my current data violates this spec)

The second style of DICOM has a directory structure where the bottom level of folders is named as A-Z and each one contains 25 files (with no suffix) which are named (in each folder) Z01-Z25.
I can open the files individually using:

```
reader->SetFileName(tempFile.c_str());
```

Instead of specifying the directory.  If I read all of the 25 in one of the bottom folders, it is a mix of different ordered chunks from different scans.  I was prepared to set up a function to skim all folders and files in the directory to find and assemble all slices associated with one scan, but so far I have been unable to find/appropriately implement a function within vtkDICOMImageReader to:

A: detect which unique series set of slices I am in (series label)

nor

B: detect my current slice number in series as well as the total series count (slice count/ series slice total)

---

I can post more source as necesary, but basically have tried monitoring all parameters in "reader" and "sliceData" while loading slices from different series and as of yet have not gotten anything to provide me with the above data.  I am assuming that either I am not appropriately updating in between slice loads and or am not looking at the right object parameters.

Any information on what I am doing wrong in terms of code or even my poor understanding of DICOM structure would be greatly appreciated!

ps: I am working in c++, but am fairly certain the usage is similar in Python

Comment: Have you tried the vtk-dicom library? (not the `vtkDICOMImageReader`, but the `vtkDICOMReader`) It is far more interesting for Dicoms, check it here: https://dgobbi.github.io/vtk-dicom/doc/api/directory.html

Comment: oh snap... no i did not.  looking at it now

Comment: sorry, I am just getting started with open source code... is vtkDICOMReader additional code that I need to bring into the vtk library?

Comment: :/ I have vtk 8.0 but cant seem to load in vtkDICOMReader, I will look further into it

Comment: Are you using Cmake? You have an option there to compile vtk dicom

Comment: Please check the appendix in this link: http://dgobbi.github.io/vtk-dicom/doc/vtk-dicom.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have posted in the comments, in this case, the vtk-dicom is more suitable for your needs. Here are some useful links:

- A tutorial on how to use vtk-dicom API to scan directories, organize your data according to series and studies: https://dgobbi.github.io/vtk-dicom/doc/api/directory.html
- The vtk-dicom documentation, with installation instructions on the Appendix:  http://dgobbi.github.io/vtk-dicom/doc/vtk-dicom.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Dicom is horribly complex and things get implemented slightly differently depending on what company's scanner the data is from and how old the system is.  In your first example it sounds like you have a simply formatted directory with individual slice files and no extra scout images so VTK is able to read in and render the slices and it looks fine.

Your second example sound like there's a more complex structure that may contain multiple series and possibly things like scout images or even non-image type Dicom files.  For dealing with this type of data you'll need some logic to read the meta-data and figure out which files you're interested in and how to assemble them.  The meta-data for the entire set is contained in a single file named "dicomdir" which should be in the top level directory.  This data is redundant with data in .dcm file headers but reading from this file saves you the trouble of scanning the header from every file individually.

VTK is an image manipulation/display library not a Dicom system.  I'm not sure they have good support for complex directory structures.  You could try `reader->SetFileName('dicomdir');` and see if they have logic to automatically handle this but I'd be a bit surprised if that worked.

If you're going to be working with complex multi-series data like this you'll probably need to use another library to extract the info you want.  I highly recommend `DCMTK`.  It's a great open-source C++ library for working with Dicom, just don't expect it to be super simple.

Comment: Yes, the second one does indeed have a scout file.  ty for the tip on the dicomdir file, I found it and will see what I can get out of it.  tbh I am not partial towards vtk, it is just want I have (because pcl uses it), and I will get DCMTK set up and try it out, thanks!

Comment: Tried setting filename to the DICOMDIR file and it spat it back out.  I'll start setting up DCMTK now

Comment: I should point out that there's a command line utility called `dcmdump` (it's part of DCMTK) that will print the contents of a `dicomdir` or individual dicom files.  That'll be a lot easier than using the c++ code directly if you're just trying to figure out which files to load.

Comment: ...idk, problem is that I need to load a few hundred files.  May as well implement a better tool for importing the data.

Answer (score 1):

You should not assume the content of a DICOM file by its name or position in the directory structure.

Instead, the root of the DICOM folder should contain a DICOMDIR file, which contains the list of files and their relationship (e.g., patient objects contain studies objects which contain series and then images).

I don't know if VTK offers a way of reading and interpreting DICOMDIR files; if not then you could try to interpret them with [dcmtk](http://dicom.offis.de/dcmtk.php.en) or [Imebra](https://imebra.com).

Disclosure: I'm the author of Imebra

Comment: You are quite right, and thank you.  As stated by all of you the DICOMDIR file is what I was missing.  All three libraries vtkDICOM, dcmtk, and Imebra can read that file and allow structured access.  As I am already using vtk elsewhere in my project, it was simply the easiest to just add vtkDICOM on rather than bring in another open source library...